# MySQL is not showing data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a website filled with articles and I would like to be able to order them by tags. Every article have a few tags associated.

I use 3 tables :

**medias** (Stand for articles)

```
+----+--------+-----+
| id | title  | ... |
+----+--------+-----+
|  1 | hello  | ... |
|  2 | hi     | ... |
+----+--------+-----+
```

**tags**

```
+----+------+-----+
| id | name | ... |
+----+------+-----+
|  1 | red  | ... |
|  2 |square| ... |
+----+------+-----+
```

**medias_tags** (In order to link the tags & media together)

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id | media_id | tag_id |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 |        1 |      1 |
|  2 |        1 |      2 |
|  3 |        2 |      2 |
+----+----------+--------+
```

So far i'm using this MySQL/PHP code to order the articles by tags, which is working (I purposely removed the pagination conditions for better understanding) :

$bdd

```
try{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB;charset=utf8', 'username', 'pass');}catch(Exception $e) { die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}



if(isset($_GET['tag'])){
    $tag_name_1 = htmlspecialchars($_GET['tag']);
    $req_tag = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM tags WHERE name = ?');
    $req_tag->execute(array($tag_name_1));
    $data_tag = $req_tag->fetch();
    $ttag_id = $data_tag['id'];     

    $q = 'SELECT * 
          FROM medias 
          JOIN medias_tags 
          ON medias.id=medias_tags.media_id 
          WHERE medias_tags.tag_id ='.$ttag_id.' 
          ORDER BY date DESC 
          LIMIT '.$start.','.$limit;       
    }

    $req_mda_list = $bdd->query($q);
```

The issue is when I want to display all the tags associated to the article. **$mda_tags_list** is blank.

```
while ($data_mda = $req_mda_list->fetch()){

    $mda_id = $data_mda['id'];
    $mda_title = $data_mda['title'];

    #Get media tags
    $req_mda_tags = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM medias_tags WHERE media_id = ?');
    $req_mda_tags->execute(array($mda_id));      

    $mda_tags_list = null;

    while ($data_mda_tags = $req_mda_tags->fetch()){
        $tag_id = $data_mda_tags['tag_id'];

        $req_tag_name = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM tags WHERE id = ?');
        $req_tag_name->execute(array($tag_id));
        $data_tag_name = $req_tag_name->fetch();

        $mda_tags_list .= '<a href="http://www.website.com/tags/'.$data_tag_name['name'].'">'.$data_tag_name['name'].'</a> ';
}

    echo $mda_title.' - '.$mda_tags_list;

}
```

What I actually get :

```
Order by tag -> Square

Title1 - Tag :
Title5 - Tag : 
Title6 - Tag :
```

What I'm trying to get :

```
Order by tag -> Square

Title1 - Tag : Square, Red, Thank
Title5 - Tag : Yellow, Square, You
Title6 - Tag : Square, Blue, Stackoverflow
```

Comment: Are you sure your binding works? It's strange you use variables in your first select directly and in the second and third you use param binding. What is $bbd? Are you using PDO directly, a library abstraction layer or your own abstraction layer?

Comment: Why not combine your two queries into `SELECT * FROM tags WHERE id IN (SELECT tag_id FROM medias_tags WHERE media_id = ?)`? That way, you wouldn't need to call the database as often. I agree that something doesn't seem right; you can look at PDO errors with the [`errorInfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) method.

Comment: @R.Chappell I edited my question with $bdd (db). The reason I use variables in my first select and biding in my second is that I pretty much copy/paste my pagination script. However I don't think it can be a issue right?

Comment: Ok, we'll I can't spot anything obvious... What you can do is check the response from `$req_mda_tags->execute();` if it's false then there was an error. As @ChrisForrence said, use erroInfo to check what the error was. Failing that we can assume the issue is with your PHP.

Comment: @R.Chappell I've been trying to detect any error but it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done is simplified your code, I've reduced your SQL down to one statement and I've added some very basic error checking:

```
$tagName = htmlspecialchars($_GET['tag']);

$sql = "SELECT 
        medias.*,
        GROUP_CONCAT(tags2.name) AS allTags
    FROM
        medias
        -- Get the media tags
        JOIN medias_tags ON medias.id = medias_tags.media_id
        -- Join on the tags so we can add a where condition
        JOIN tags ON medias_tags.tag_id = tags.id
        -- Rejoin tags again, this won't be used as a condition hence the left
        LEFT JOIN tags AS tags2 ON medias_tags.tag_id = tags2.id
    WHERE
        -- Only get medias where it has a matching tag name
        tag.name = :name
    GROUP BY
        medias.id
    ORDER BY
        date DESC
    LIMIT
        :offset, :limit";

$sth = $bdd->prepare($sql);

// Did it prepare ok?
if (!$sth) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
    exit;
}

$err = $sth->execute(array(':name' => $tagName, ':offset' => $start, ':limit' => $limit));

// Did it execute ok?
if (!$sth) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
    exit;
}

foreach ($sth->fetchAll() as $row) {
    $tags = explode(',', $row['allTags']);

    echo $row['title'] . ' - ';

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        echo '<a href="http://www.website.com/tags/' . $tag . '">' . $tag . '</a> ';
    }
}
```

It's possible my SQL comments need removing, also this won't work correctly if your tags contain commas. You can specify a different separator if needed to get avoid that.

Basically, it's just to reduce the areas which could fail and to catch the likely areas. I'm only attempting to output as per your example and what it looks like your code is doing, hopefully this gives you something to work with that will achieve your goals.

Comment: Found out the error was coming from medias_tags['id'] which was messing up with medias['id']. It's working now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For the medias to get all tags, you can use the query below:

```
SELECT medias.id,medias.title,GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name) as tag
FROM medias 
JOIN medias_tags ON medias.id = medias_tags.media_id
JOIN tags ON medias_tags.tag_id = tags.id
GROUP BY medias.id
```

To get all medias along with tags if available else blank, you can use the query below:

```
SELECT medias.id,medias.title,GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name) as tag
FROM medias 
LEFT JOIN medias_tags ON medias.id = medias_tags.media_id
LEFT JOIN tags ON medias_tags.tag_id = tags.id
GROUP BY medias.id
```